# @Autowired more superior to nested Inner bean constructor?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am learning the Spring framework and have encountered an issue while doing the same. I have two classes, namely `Car`, `Tyre`. `Car` class contains a `Tyre` object as class-variable.

**Car.java**

```
package com.mrityu.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Car implements Vehicle{

   @Autowired
   private Tyre tyre;

   public Tyre getTyre() {      
       return tyre;
   }

   public void setTyre(Tyre tyre) {
       this.tyre = tyre;
   }

   public void drive() {
       System.out.println("CAR.." + tyre );
   }

   public Car() {
       System.out.println( "Default Constructor of Car Called" );
   }

   public Car(Tyre tyre) {
       super();
       System.out.println( "Car Constructor Called" );
       System.out.println( tyre );
       this.tyre = tyre;
   }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
       return "Car [tyre=" + tyre + "]";
  }


}
```

**Tyre.java**

```
package com.mrityu.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class Tyre {


    private String Brand;

    public String getBrand() {
        System.out.println( "Getter Called" );
        return Brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        System.out.println( "Setter Called" );
        Brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tyre [Brand=" + Brand + "]";
    }

    public Tyre() {
        super();
        this.Brand = "CEAT";
        System.out.println( "Default Constructor of Tyre Called");
    }
    public Tyre(String brand) {
        super();
        System.out.println( "Tyre Constructor Called" );
        Brand = brand;
    }

 }
```

Below is my XML Config File and App.java

**App.java**

```
package com.mrityu.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml"); 
      System.out.println("Beans Created..." );
      Car obj = (Car) context.getBean("car");
      System.out.println( obj );
   }
}
```

**Spring.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<!-- bean definitions go here -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mrityu.spring"></context:component-scan> 


<bean id = 'tyre' class = "com.mrityu.spring.Tyre">  
    <constructor-arg value = "CEAT"></constructor-arg>      
</bean> 

<bean id = "car" class = "com.mrityu.spring.Car">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id = 'tyre' class = "com.mrityu.spring.Tyre">  
            <constructor-arg value = "MRF"></constructor-arg>       
        </bean> 
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

On running `App.java` the output is coming as:-

```
Tyre Constructor Called
Car Constructor Called
Tyre [Brand=MRF]
Tyre Constructor Called
Beans Created...
Car [tyre=Tyre [Brand=CEAT]]
```

What I am unable to understand is even though I have defined a nested inner bean constructor in the XML file for `car` with `brand` as `MRF` why my final output, i.e., the bean of `car` is having the brand as `CEAT` even though I can see that the `car` bean is being created with `brand` as `MRF` as can be seen in the output.

P.S. I know that I require either the @Autowired or inner bean constructor, but I was doing it to understand the working of XML and annotations better.

Comment: In your XML config the two Type bean have the same `id` so when Spring is creating the second it is overwriting the first.

Comment: @Tyutyutyu Even after changing the `id` output remains the same.

Comment: You have 2 cars constructed, 1 with the `CEAT` and the other with `MRF`. This is due to the fact your `Car` is also an `@Component` and you have enabled component-scanning. Now as the id of the cars are both `car` only one will survive, the last one being created that is. If you name your `Car` in XML `car1` you should be able to see this. Or do `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Car.class)` to get both.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed the `id` of nested bean constructor to `car1` in the XML as suggested by you and executed `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Car.class)` which gives me two car beans each having `brand` as `CEAT` which is unexpected as we would expect one bean each of `MRF` and `CEAT` respectively.

Moreover, as clear from the output attached in the question, it can be noted that `MRF` is being created at last but still the `CEAT` is getting survived but you are of the opinion that the last one being created will survive. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Because you are mixing both annotations and xml. After the construction the bean is being replaced by the other `Tyre` due to the `@Autowired`. The inner `Tyre` instance isn't an autowiring candidate (on top level beans are) and hence it will get replaced after construction.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay. I understand now. Thanks!